# Sudo won't execute command as another user

Tags: linux, shell, boot, unicorn

I'm trying to get a unicorn server to start when the server boots. I've created a shell script which works if I log as the ubuntu user and run

```
/etc/init.d/unicorn start
```

**Shell script**

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
start)
    cd /home/ubuntu/projects/asbest/current/
    unicorn_rails -c /home/ubuntu/projects/asbest/current/config/unicorn.rb -D -E production

;;
stop)
    if ps aux | awk '{print $2 }' | grep `cat ~/projects/asbest/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`> /dev/null; then kill `cat ~/projects/asbest/current/tmp/pids/uni$
;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
;;
esac
```

When I rebooted the server I noticed that the unicorn server wasn't listening to a socket. Since I ran the code succesfully as the ubuntu user I modified the script to let it always use the ubuntu user via sudo.

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
start)
    cd /home/ubuntu/projects/asbest/current/
    sudo -u ubuntu unicorn_rails -c /home/ubuntu/projects/asbest/current/config/unicorn.rb -D -E production
;;
stop)
    if ps aux | awk '{print $2 }' | grep `cat ~/projects/asbest/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`> /dev/null; then sudo -u ubuntu kill `cat ~/projects/asbest/current/tmp/pids/uni$
;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
;;
esac
```

After rebooting unicorn still wouldn't start, so I tried running the script from the command line. Now I get the following error

```
sudo: unicorn_rails: command not found
```

I've searched high and low to what could cause this, but I'm afraid I've tapped my limited understanding of Linux. From what I can understand is that although sudo should use the ubuntu user to execute the commands, it still uses the environment of the root user, which isn't configured to run ruby or unicorn. Does anybody have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use global vars `UNICORN_*` like this:

```
UNICORN_HOME=/the/path
UNICORN_RAIL=${UNICORN_HOME}/unicorn_rail
UNICORN_CONFIG=${UNICORN_HOME}/config/unicorn.rb
UNICORN_PID=${UNICORN_HOME}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
UNICORN_USER=ubuntu

sudo -u ${UNICORN_USER} ${UNICORN_RAIL} -c $UNICORN_CONFIG -D -E production
```

Another good way is to extract global vars in `/etc/default/unicorn`:

```
UNICORN_HOME=/the/path
UNICORN_RAIL=${UNICORN_HOME}/unicorn_rail
UNICORN_CONFIG=${UNICORN_HOME}/config/unicorn.rb
UNICORN_PID=${UNICORN_HOME}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
UNICORN_USER=ubuntu
```

and in your init script add change all vars by:

```
if [ -f /etc/default/unicorn ]; then
    . /etc/default/unicorn
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sudo`, try using `su [username]` and then execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path to `unicorn_rails`:

```
UNICORN_HOME=/home/ubuntu/projects/asbest/current
cd $UNICORN_HOME
sudo -u ubuntu $UNICORN_HOME/unicorn_rails -c $UNICORN_HOME/config/unicorn.rb -D -E production
```

Have you configured sudo appropriately?